# Is there a need to reload or restart nginx on a high request nginx load balancer?

Tags: nginx

My question is given that I'm using nginx as a load balancer for some services.  Is there a need to reload nginx if there are no changes to the server after a while to prevent memory leaks? or something of the sort? Perhaps to make it not run sluggish after a while?

Comment: What problems are you encountering?

Comment: @harrymc given the traffic varies during the day with peaks in the morning after noon, and none at night.  At times the time for a request to initiate at times takes for ever.  It doesn't time out, but may take minutes to start.  but i refresh, try again, goes fine

Comment: If you have a resource leak and can't identify it, then restart or reboot at night is the only solution.